# binary_function, compiler error on call

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have an array of bytes which have event ids and event data for some ids:
{0x1, 0x2, 0x32} // e.g., 0x1 - eventId, 0x2 - its data, 0x32 - another event id.

To parse it and create Event objects I've created several binary functions which know how to interpret event data bytes and a map with an event id as a key and a pointer to std::binary_function as a value:

```
map<uint8_t, SspProtocol::EventDataParser*>
```

where SspProtocol::EventDataParser is:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t; // declared in file stdint.h
[...]
class SspProtocol {
        typedef std::binary_function<const std::vector<uint8_t>*, std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator*, Event> EventDataParser;
[...]
}
```

I get a compiler error when I try to call this functor:

```
vector<SspProtocol::Event> SspProtocol::poll() {    
    vector<uint8_t> data = sendCommand(POLL);
    vector<Event> events;
    const vector<uint8_t>& const_data = data; // (*)

    for (vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator i = const_data.begin(); i != const_data.end();) {
        map<uint8_t, SspProtocol::EventDataParser*>& parsers = Event::eventParser();
        EventDataParser& parser = *parsers[*i]; // (**)
        Event event = parser(&const_data, &i); // (***)

        events.push_back(event);
    }

    return events;
}
```

I get error on the line (***):

```
error: no match for call to 
‘(protocols::ssp::SspProtocol::EventDataParser 
{aka std::binary_function<const std::vector<unsigned char>*, 
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned char*, 
std::vector<unsigned char> >*, protocols::ssp::SspProtocol::Event>
}) (const std::vector<unsigned char>*, 
std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator*)’
```

Why does my g++ compiler uses __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator* and why it is not compatible with const_iterator*? What can I do about it?

P.S.: I especially added const reference on the line (*) to make the first template argument have const-qualifier and I also devided the functor call and getting the functor from the map (see line (**)).
This gave me that the error is on a functor call, it's not connected to the map and auto_ptr.

P.P.S.:Here is an example event parser:

```
class SspProtocol::EventWithoutDataParser
    : public SspProtocol::EventDataParser {
bool ackEvent_;

public:
EventWithoutDataParser(bool ackEvent = false) : ackEvent_(ackEvent) {}

Event operator()(const vector<uint8_t>* data, vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator* i) {
    Event event(*(*i));
    ++(*i);
    return event;
}

bool ackEvent() const { return ackEvent_; }
};
```

Comment: To start with, I don't see a need to use pointers for the functions, use references instead. It will not solve your problem, but it will be simpler to use (no more dereferencing weirdness for example), as well as be more "C++-ish".

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg:
I now think I can just use map<uint8_t, SspProtocol::DataParser>, it's just a struct anyway, so why not copy it to the map.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm wrong here, I can't use by-value struct, the object of derived type will be sliced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the documentation for std::binary_function (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function). It is a base class for binary functions that does nothing but document the argument types and return type. It does not define the actual operator() (a,b) so obviously it cannot be invoked on an instance of/pointer to this type. Instead, try using

```
std::function<Event(const std::vector<uint8_t>*, std::vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator*)>
```

*by-value* (not by pointer, it already is an advanced sort of function pointer) to store your parser functions. An std::function can be checked for emptiness and invoked.

Comment: It is worth noting that `std::binary` and friends are deprecated.

Comment: Also, as mentioned before... Don't use pointers everywhere... A vector is typically passed by const-ref (unless you explicitly want to allow nullptr) to avoid unnecessary copying and an iterator can usually be passed by-value due to its negligible storing/copying cost (again, unless you want to allow for nullptr).

Comment: @hinrichj: Thank you. I somehow thought binary_function is needed to create a functor... Now I get it, of I've changed pointers to references, I can't send an iterator by value, because the parsers update it (they increment it). What do you mean by 'by-value' to store parser functions? map<key, EventDataParser>? I can't do so, EventDataParser is a base class, so the concrete objects will be sliced. I can't use references, because I don't store parsers elsewhere, they are owned by the map.

Comment: @hinrichj: I've created myown functor (class with operator()) and and store a pointer to it in the map. Now it works. I cannot use std::function because it is c++11 feature and the project is in c++03. Thanks for the link to the documentation.

Comment: @Arks: sorry to hear you're stuck at C++03 :) If you're allowed to use boost you have alternatives for most of C++11 (and more)... If you want the function to modify the arguments passed, the C++ way is to pass them via non-const reference (for your iterator argument).

Comment: @heinrichj no boost also) I have quite specific project in this way, 'caused by binaries distribution channel and OS limitations. Anyway, it now compiles fine, and I've also changed pointers to const/non-const references in arguments as you had suggested.